# yUP on Python graphics.py from prof J Zelle

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I am having some problems trying to enter information through the screen window, using graphics.py from Prof. J Zelle, I am reading some additional tutorial on 
"http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html?highlight=yup"
and here I find that all examples starts with

```
win = GraphWin('Face', 200, 150) # give title and dimensions
win.yUp() # make right side up coordinates!
```

I am using the graphics.py download from http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/, that appears to be at # Version 4.2 5/26/2011, and on it I cant find the  win.yUp .

Can somebody pls provide the information how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

As the tutorial you linked to [explains](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html) in the first paragraph, "My slight elaboration of his [i.e. Prof. Zelle] package is graphics.py in the example programs."

You want the version from http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/index.html instead.  Download the zip file linked to after "Example programs needed to test out code used in the tutorial".